# Admob Robovm Eclipse build with error : Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: libgdx, admob, robovm

I'm intergrating admob binding for my robovm-libgdx project at github : https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/admob
by follow this document: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx#ios-setup-robovm

In debug with devices step, i got an error:

```
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]   "_, referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]       l001 in libadmob.a(GADGestureUtil.o)
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]   "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]       l001 in libadmob.a(GADGestureUtil.o)
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libadmob.a(GADOpener.o)
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libadmob.a(GADOpener.o)
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]   "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:57 AM: [ERROR]       -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libadmob.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libadmob.a(GADDevice.o)
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]   "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]       -[GADNetworkChecker stopNetworkChecking] in libadmob.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]   "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]       -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libadmob.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]   "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
6/20/14 10:02:58 AM: [ERROR]       -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libadmob.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
6/20/14 10:02:59 AM: [ERROR] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
6/20/14 10:02:59 AM: [ERROR] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
6/20/14 10:02:59 AM: [ERROR] Build fail
```

I need you help for resolve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

i've solved this problem with adding three more frameworks (MessageUI, SystemConfiguration, CoreTelephony) - for now my frameworks in robovm.xml looks like:

```
<frameworks>
  <framework>UIKit</framework>
  <framework>OpenGLES</framework>
  <framework>QuartzCore</framework>
  <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
  <framework>OpenAL</framework>
  <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
  <framework>AVFoundation</framework>
  <framework>MessageUI</framework>
  <framework>SystemConfiguration</framework>
  <framework>CoreTelephony</framework>
</frameworks>
```

Comment: Please, how can I add these frameworks in Android Studio? I can't fint the downloads anywhere

Comment: Some time goes by since I solved this, but you don't have to download those frameworks. Those frameworks are system frameworks from iOS. The robovm.xml just defines which system frameworks your Xcode project needs.